# Components don't show at all

Tags: octobercms

I cannot get any components I have installed via the october website to work. I have dragged them into my pages but nothing shows on the frontend. I have tried multiple plugins and all do the same. The only component that works is the built in ToDo list.

e.g {% component 'EvList' %}

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your folder structure is important. I faced the same problem since the components on backend are running well, but the front end page still does not show the component. before and my issue was naming convention. If your hosting is Linux, check case sensitivity.

The components folder should be:

- YourComponent.php
- yourcomponent **(this should be lowercase)**

  - default.htm

Comment: Not the first time I make that mistake and have to be reminded about it here because I always forget, this lowercase convention don't make much sense to me.
What's even weirder is that it runs fine on my local environment even though I'm using Homestead (debian buster), only production environment (CentOS) get this problem.

Comment: This doesn't work as mentioned in the Docs. Making All lowercase is not working in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm sure you've done something wrong but anyway try to write `{% component 'component_name_here' %}`

And in the CMS section in the backend then focus your mouse on the word `component` and you'll be able to see this icon in the upper right side in the CMS.

[image]

When you click on this sign October will drag the component original code and drop it in front of you directly so you can edit the component code.

I'm sure if you couldn't see this sign or when you click on it nothing happens then you absolutely you've done something wrong.
Anyway try this out, I hope I could help you.

Comment: I can see that button and the component code however nothing appears on the page still, almost like there is no styling for it. I would just like to add I am running OctoberCMS on Windows Server 2012 using IIS.

Comment: That means your component works well, so save your layout and make sure that the code of your component is in the page in the browser.
If it's there you'll have to edit your CSS or anything that preventing the component to be displayed.

Comment: I am having the same issue and none of these answers work

Comment: As well as the embedded code {% component 'compName' %}, you also need to include this bit at the top [compName]. This puzzled me for a long time and it was only when I noticed [demoTodo] at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Ahmed, please refer to the OctoberCMS documentation for Components: https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/components.

After installing any plugin, logout and login again for refreshing the CMS.